# import array of objects with a module as a property returns undefined when import twice

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import an array of objects that has a module as a property. The first file that imports the object has no problem, but the second one has undefined.

```
// file 1
export default [
  {
    property1: 'bar',
    property2: 'foo',
    property3: require('./somefile').default,
  },
  {
    property1: 'bar',
    property2: 'foo',
    property3: require('./file3').default,
  },
];


// file 2
import myArray from './file1';
console.log(myArray) // everything ok


// file 3
import myArrayAgain from './file1';
console.log(myArrayAgain); // undefined
```

here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-hodgkin-uk7q7

Comment: You missed the ‘from’ in the import in file 3

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to demo this situation or guide us about the config of your project? I'm having a hard time recreating your issue.

Comment: sure @FaisalRahmanAvash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your codesandbox example and I think you have a cyclic dependency. `file1` depends on `file2`, but the console.log in `file2` depends on `file1` which would not have had been evaluated that point.

Now, in the example in the description, `file1` depends on the result of `file3`and, therefore, the result  of file3 cannot depend on the result of `file1`

So, consider making `file1` require some other file as long as it's not `file3`

```
//file 1
export default [
  {
    property1: 'bar',
    property2: 'foo',
    property3: require('./somefile').default,
  },
  {
    property1: 'bar',
    property2: 'foo',
    property3: require('./file4').default,
  },
];
```